# Why PS5 is showing a game as "In Library" and also an option to purchase?

Tags: playstation-plus, ps5

I recently bought a PS5 with a PS Plus Extra Subscription. I wanted Bloodborne and Demon Souls as the first few games. However, I found it quite confusing. I claimed Bloodbrone and Demon Souls as they were available in my PS Plus Membership catalogue. However, the PlayStation Store still has the option to buy Bloodborne, while there is no option to buy Demon's Souls. (Please check photos below).

**So, do I own the games or not?**

P.S - This is my first ever Console. The prices are in INR.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It happens the same with God of War, I own a digital copy and the store lets me buy another version for €19.99:

[image]

My speculation is that you own the base game version, but the store has also one labeled as "Playstation Hits", which is the same game, but is managed as a different version.

Bloodborne has a "Playstation Hits" version, too. Demon's Souls does not.

Comment: So, I own the game right? The price tags are just a different version, and not the same game !!

Comment: Yes. When you see "in library" you definitely own the game, no need to purchase it again. Of course, as @Princess Ada suggests, if you have redeemed a game from PS plus you can play it only with an active subscription.

Answer (score 1):

The games included with the PlayStation Plus Extra subscription are not permanently yours to own. You can continue to play them as long as you are still subscribed to PS Plus Extra (or Premium), and the games are still included in the collection, but if either of those things changes you will no longer be able to play them without buying a copy. Think of this as the difference between watching a show that is included with your Netflix subscription and buying a DVD so you can watch it whenever you want.

If you intend to keep hold of your PS Plus Extra subscription then there is probably no point buying the games now, but the option is there for you if for example you decide not to renew your subscription but want to keep playing.

A similar thing happens with the monthly games. In this case so long as you claim them while they are available you can continue playing for as long as you remain subscribed to any level of PS Plus, but you still have the option to buy permanently so you can keep the games even without a subscription.

Comment: I know that, but why some games have a purchase option (like Bloodborne), while other ones do not have it (Demon Souls, Spiderman, etc.)